# How to show $||T||= \sup\{{||T(x)|| \over ||x||} : x \in X , x \ne 0\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be normed $\mathbb K$ linear space . $X \ne \{0\}$ and let $T$ be a $\mathbb K$ linear function. Then $$\|T\|= \sup\left\{\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X , x \ne 0 \right\}.$$ Here $\|T\| = \sup \{\|T(x)\|: x \in X, \|x\| \leq 1 \}$

How can I prove the inequality $$\|T\| \leq \sup \left\{\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|} :x \in X, x \neq 0\right\}$$ because the other inequality  I have done.

Please someone give some hints.

Thank you..

Comment: Let $x \neq 0$ and $y = \frac1{\|x\|} x$. Then $\|y\|\le 1$. What can you say about $\frac{\|T(y)\|}{\|y\|}$? Note also that you can prove $\|T\| = \sup \{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}: \|x\| =1\}$.